# How to find the transform from an empiric distribution to another empiric distribution

Tags: distributions, data-transformation

I have two datasets, each dataset is a pool of samples, and each sample contains multiple observations. Data-wise, we can represent one sample as a vector of floats, and a dataset as a matrix where each row is a sample.

I would like to find a transform to project the first dataset into the "space" of the second dataset. I think I am looking for a way to estimate and then project an empirical distribution into another empirical distribution. There might be a dependency between samples of one dataset, but not between datasets.

Bonus reward if the answer also suggests a way to account for the number of samples (because there is a big dataset and the other one is much smaller, thus a distribution estimation will likely be much more approximate for the latter).

Clarification: I have (and can't get) no apriori on the underlying distribution of any of the datasets. They are generated by a natural phenomenon, and no theory model correctly these distributions yet.

/EDIT: I will try to clarify with a concrete example close to what I am working on.

Let's say I am working on a machine learning application to automatically recognize objects shapes in a scanned image. To make it simpler, let's say these images are only in grayscale (no color, only pixel intensity remains).

The problem I am facing is that **I have images coming from several different scanners, and each scanner has a different "intensity space"**, so that it is difficult to transpose a machine learning model learnt on one scanner to the next scanner, because of the scanner-induced variability in intensity.

More formally, using pseudo-Python code, my data and code would look like this:

```
# Images are represented as a row vector, each value is one pixel intensity
# They are the samples
scanner1_im1 = [1, 255, 3, 73, ...]
scanner1_im2 = [4, 83, 2, 190, ...]
scanner2_im1 = [8, 29, 1, ...]
scanner2_im2 = [37, 29, 4, ...]

# We can constitute a pool of image samples for each scanner, which I call a dataset
scanner1_images = [scanner1_im1, scanner1_im2]
scanner2_images = [scanner2_im1, scanner2_im2]

# TODO: normalization step, where the scanner2_images gets normalized/projected into scanner1_images space, or whatever technique that would allow to represent both datasets in an approximately similar space
scanner2_images_norm = norm_project_images(scanner2_images, scanner1_images)

# Machine learning modeling on normalized images
ml.learn(scanner1_images, scanner2_images_norm)
```

What statistical/probabilistic techniques may I use to project all scanners/datasets into a similar space of intensities (and thus reduce inter-scanner variability while retaining inter-images/intra-scanner variability as much as possible)?

Comment: The question is unclear: what do you mean by a pool of sample? Do you seek a distribution $F(x)$ such that $x$ is one sample?

Comment: I tried to clarify with the second sentence, but with your notation, it would be `F(X1, X2, ..., Xn)` where `Xi` is a vector.

Comment: To clarify, because this might be a difficult edge case, `X1, ..., Xn` might all have some intrinsic variability, but I am interested in the whole variability, the parameters of the "parent" distribution that is shared across all Xs. If I am not clear enough, please tell me.

Comment: Also I expect the difference between Xi and Yi (2nd dataset) to be greater than any Xi vs Xj or Yi vs Yj. This is this (extrinsic) difference that I would like to quantify and reduce, even if approximately.

Comment: Do you have a method to solve your problem in the case df1 has 1 column, m rows; df2 has 1 column, n rows; and samples of df1 are independent, samples of df2 are independent? If you can describe the problem and a solution is this case, it could help us to understand the problem clearly

Comment: Try to show with a snippet how your data looks like.

Comment: I added an example that is close to mine. I cannot show a snippet of my data as I did not generate it yet, but this example should be very analog.

Comment: There is not enough information for a solution yet. We need to know something about the scanners and how they differ, or something about the things being scanned, to get anywhere.

Comment: Q1: In your example, do you have images of the same object taken with both scanners and, if so, are these images spatially co-registered (e.g. does each pixel of `scanner1_im1` represent the same position on the same object as the matching pixel in `scanner2_im1`?). Q2: Does the way the scanners differ change across space/pixels, or is it constant? Q3: Do the scanners have different noise characteristics (and does this matter to you)?

Comment: @Paul: There is about a 100 different parameters or more than can influence the way the scanners behave: this is exactly the problem. And in addition there is no model that quantify the impact of each. I cannot model the parameters explicitly, it needs to be done approximately and implicitly from empiric observations, that's the gist of my question.

Comment: @user20160: Q1: No, but we can consider the objects similar enough that an average image from one dataset should be expected close to the other dataset (eg: same kind of object such as apples, but the shape and color can change, although the orientation is the same). The images can be co-registered (even non-linearly, but keep in mind that we might be comparing different  apples "flavours"). Q2: If you mean to ask whether the variability per scanner change from scan to scan, yes but we can consider it negligible. If you mean in terms of space, then yes the variability can be anywhere.

Comment: @user20160: Q3: The scanners have different noise characteristics, in fact this is I want to reduce (ie, the difference in scanner's noise/variability). Q1 again: to make it clearer: if you take any object from dataset D1 and compare to an object in D2, then you can't expect same to be the same, but if you take the "average" model of an object in D1 and compare with the average of D2, then you can expect to be the same (this is an approximation but it's OK). However due to scanner's induced variability, the average can be very different between datasets.

Comment: How do you know that you even need to do this? The right machine learning technique could very well be robust to the differences between scanners. Convolutional neural nets can recognize letters and numbers under all sorts of distortions, illumination conditions, noise, corruption...

Comment: This question needs to be modified to give a clear explanation for what the vector of pixels actually represents: Do they represent an image in two dimensions?  If so, what are the dimensions, and how are the pixels ordered?  Are the vectors of pixels from the scanners the same length?  If the image spaces are different, what is the difference in pixel vectors?  Etc., etc.  The information presently given is insufficient to clarify the question.

Comment: @Ben: we can consider the image in two dimensions, in a row vector (eg, first i pixels represent the first row in the image, i+i the second row of pixels, i*2+i the third row etc). They are not necessarily the same length but I'm OK if this is assumed to be equal for simplification.

Comment: @Paul: You're right that a machine learning model might account for that, I didn't think about it. But in my real application, I am not going to use a machine learning model, at least not until after more processing that is so down in the pipeline that it cannot account for differences in scanner variation. However, using a machine learning model specifically to fix the scanner variation might be a solution, feel free to propose an answer with this!

Comment: @gaborous: I hope you don't mind, but I posted a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330937/projecting-a-spatial-matrix-onto-another-spatial-matrix), in an attempt to clarify some aspects of this question.  If my question correctly interprets yours, you may feel free to steal any of it for an edit.

Comment: If you want to fix this and not just be robust to it, then you really need a model for the scanners and their variation - something much simpler than the 100 parameter model. What does the signal input/output curve look like? Is it linear? Is it the same for each pixel in the scanner? Is there spatial distortion or blur? Do you have any lab calibration data that could help constrain the solution?

Comment: You should also look deeper and try to understand the 100 parameter model. Most likely there are only a few "effective parameters" that account for most of the variation between the scanners. Any lab measurements you may have you should make use of.

Comment: You really, really can't solve this problem without more information or assumptions. It's way too ill-posed. I say that as a person who has solved similar problems in the past on space instruments. Don't fool yourself going down the path of some canned "method" that supposedly works in another discipline.

Comment: How do you even measure your success in solving this problem? If two scanners never take images of the same thing, how would you know whether differences between scanner results are because the transfer functions are off or the objects being imaged are just different?

Comment: Thank you all very much for your very helpful comments. @Paul: we can assume that the average image of each scanner is representing the same thing (eg, a table), so that's what I use as a reference (the average image of scanner A should be pretty similar to scanner B's), but of course this is an approximation... Modeling the parameters would be ofc the best way, but the scanners are changing quite fast, they are not open and doing such a study would take years if not decades.

Comment: @Ben I don't mind at all, thank you very much! Your reframing is very close to my problem, a solution to yours would surely be applicable to mine.

Comment: Assuming the average latent image is the same across scanners is a huge help for constraining the problem. Now all you need is a decent empirical model of the scanners. What drives the variation? See my questions above regarding input/output sensitivity, nonlinearity, spatial distortion, blur, etc. If a given scanner can be approximated as applying a fixed linear operator to each image, you're in business.

Comment: A fixed linear operator is not that constrained of an assumption. It can accommodate pixel dependent bias and sensitivity, spatial distortion, blur, etc. A bit of nonlinearity can probably be worked in but not too much. It would be easiest if the imaging operator was something like a multiplicative "mask" representing pixel variations in sensitivity from scanner to scanner.

Comment: @Paul: yes, I think a multiplicative mask per scanner would totally fit the bill! The issues you list are on-point, so if it can accomodate that it would be perfect. I did not think this was a possibility.

Comment: If you assume a multiplicative mask and nothing else, the best estimate for the A-to-B transfer function would just be B/A, where A and B are the average images from scanners A and B respectively. There are various ways to potentially improve upon this baseline, depending on the noise characteristics of the scanners and prior information you may have about the average image.

Comment: To make this work, the average images have to be carefully aligned so they're as similar as possible. Any differences of object position, orientation, etc must be eliminated using some image registration technique before taking the B/A ratio.

Comment: Handling all of these issues at once (sensitivity, blur, etc) would be pretty difficult. You need to pick one or two most important issues and handle those, or try to handle them one at a time / separately. The important point is that if you have linearity, the operator of averaging over all input images commutes with the scanner transfer function, so you can figure things out from the observed average images rather than the latent "true" average images which you don't have.

Comment: @Paul please post this as an answer, you can consider perfect co-registration to be possible (in practice we have algorithms to do that in my specific field). I am not sure the real transform is linear, but it's perfectly fine for me to do that as an approximation of the real transform if I make this a clear assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the field that you are interested in is called **Calibration transfer** or more generally Transfer learning. A lot of litterature can be found in the Spectroscopy field which I believe is quite close to image processing in terms of methods.

There are two different situations:

Either you have common images that have been scanned by the different scanners, in that case, I will just describe a bit the simpler and the most used methods. A review of all different methods can be found here [1]

- One of the easiest and oldest one: A method that has been developed by Wang et al [2]. The underlying principle is quite simple: a multi response and multi variate regression between the pixels response of the original instrument and the second.
- I believe the most used one now is the double window piecewise direct standardization (DWPS). Which is somehow similar to the simplest one but you using a size defined window to regress each pixel. [3]

If you don't have common images scanned by each scanner (all the images are different) there are two different approaches:

(1) The samples from the initial scanner can be reweighted in order to have the closest features distribution than the samples from the new scanner. A numerous of methods have been developed to find the appropriate weights [4,5,6,7,8]. Then you will have to re-train the model with the reweighted initial samples to predict on the new scanner.

(2) Then I think it's the approach you are most interested in: you can re-estimated a feature representation where samples form the old and new scanner are in closer proximity. Some methods have been developed to find the new representation space, you can find them here:[9,10,11]

The source 11 is a good review of all methods!

These sources in general are not specifically for image processing (and I changed the term 'wavelength' to pixel) but I belive the methods can be used for it. I don't think they explicitely take into account the size of each dataset. Hope this helps anyway!

**References**

[1] Feudale, R. N., Woody, N. A., Tan, H., Myles, A. J., Brown, S. D., & Ferré, J. (2002). Transfer of multivariate calibration models: a review. Chemometrics and Intelligent Laboratory Systems, 64(2), 181-192.

[2] Y.D. Wang, D.J. Veltkamp, B.R. Kowalski, Anal. Chem. 63
(1991) 2750–2756.

[3] Greensill, C. V., Wolfs, P. J., Spiegelman, C. H., & Walsh, K. B. (2001). Calibration transfer between PDA-based NIR spectrometers in the NIR assessment of melon soluble solids content. Applied spectroscopy, 55(5), 647-653.

[4] Huang, J., Smola, A. J., Gretton, A., Borgwardt, K. M., and Scholkopf, B.: Correcting Sample Selection Bias by Unlabeled Data, in: Pro-
5 ceedings of the 19th International Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems, NIPS’06, pp. 601–608, MIT Press, Cambridge,
MA, USA, http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2976456.2976532, 2006.

[5] Sugiyama, M., Nakajima, S., Kashima, H., Buenau, P. V., and Kawanabe, M.: Direct Importance Estimation with Model Selection
and Its Application to Covariate Shift Adaptation, in: Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 20, edited 63 by Platt, J. C., Koller, D., Singer, Y., and Roweis, S. T., pp. 1433–1440, Curran Associates, Inc., http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3248-direct-importance-estimation-with-model-selection-and-its-application-to-covariate-shift-adaptation.pdf, 2008.

[6]Kim, S., Kano, M., Nakagawa, H., and Hasebe, S.: Estimation of active pharmaceutical ingredients content using locally
weighted partial least squares and statistical wavelength selection, International Journal of Pharmaceutics, 421, 269 – 274,
https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijpharm.2011.10.007, 2011.

[7] Hazama, K. and Kano, M.: Covariance-based locally weighted partial least squares for high-performance adaptive modeling, Chemometrics
25 and Intelligent Laboratory Systems, 146, 55 – 62, https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chemolab.2015.05.007, 2015.

[8]Zhang, X., Kano, M., and Li, Y.: Locally weighted kernel partial least squares regression based on sparse nonlinear fea30
tures for virtual sensing of nonlinear time-varying processes, Computers & Chemical Engineering, 104, 164 – 171,
https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compchemeng.2017.04.014, 2017.

[9]Culp, M. and Michailidis, G.: An Iterative Algorithm for Extending Learners to a Semi-Supervised Setting, Journal of Computational and
20 Graphical Statistics, 17, 545–571, https://doi.org/10.1198/106186008X344748, 2008.

[10] Gujral, P., Amrhein, M., Ergon, R., Wise, B. M., and Bonvin, D.: On multivariate calibration with unlabeled data, Journal of Chemometrics,
25, 456–465, https://doi.org/10.1002/cem.1389, 2011.

[11] an, S. J. and Yang, Q.: A Survey on Transfer Learning, IEEE Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering, 22, 1345–1359,
https://doi.org/10.1109/TKDE.2009.191, 2010.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will review all these references! I spotted spectroscopy methods before but I was not sure they were applicable to other domains, I will have a look!