# Projecting an image matrix onto another image matrix

Tags: data-transformation, matrix, image-processing

This question is an attempt to re-frame [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327937/how-to-find-the-transform-from-an-empiric-distribution-to-another-empiric-distri?noredirect=1#comment626785_327937) on this forum that was of interest to a user dealing with two-dimensional image data from two scanners.  If I have misunderstood the linked question then I still wish to pose this as an independent question.

---

Suppose you have two black-and-white scanners that can take images of things.  An image on the either of the scanners can be represented by a real matrix, where the values in the matrix represent pixel intensities in the scan, and the matrix indices represent two-dimensional spacial coordinates (so the scanned area is assumed to be a rectangle).  Since the images are black-and-white, each pixel can be measured as a single real value measuring the intensity of the whiteness or blackness.  We denote the scanners and images using the following notation:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Scanner} & & \text{Image}  & & \text{Image Specifications} \\
\mathcal{S} \text{ } \text{ } & & \text{ } \text{ } \boldsymbol{X} = \{X_{i,j} \} & & \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } n \times m \text{ real matrix} \\ 
\mathcal{S}^* & & \boldsymbol{X}^* = \{X_{i,j}^* \} & & n^* \times m^* \text{ real matrix}
\end{matrix}$$

The scanners in this problem may have the same dimensions or different dimensions, depending on the specification of the dimension values.  Each scanner also has different properties in terms of how it scans an image.  For example, one scanner might give systematically more/less intense pixel measurements.

**The statistical problem of interest:** Suppose we have a set of objects and we use the scanners to take images of them at random.  We use scanner $\mathcal{S}$ to take images $\boldsymbol{X}_1, ..., \boldsymbol{X}_N$ and we use scanner $\mathcal{S}^*$ to take images $\boldsymbol{X}_1^*, ..., \boldsymbol{X}_{N^*}^*$.  (Remember that each of these observed values is an image matrix.)  We would like to 'convert' the images from the second scanner to predict what they would look like if the same objects had een scanned on the first scanner.

**The question:** What is an appropriate statistical procedure to convert the images $\boldsymbol{X}_1^*, ..., \boldsymbol{X}_{N^*}^*$ to image matrices from the first scanner, representing predicted images of what the same scan would have looked like if done on the first scanner.  If more information is needed, please feel free to make and state your further assumptions.  (Note: Because of the possible disparity in dimensions of the objects, scaling is allowed, and you can also assume that there may be some cropping done if the dimensions of the scanners are not proportional.)